# Change dtype in Sentinel-2 .jp2 images

Tags: sentinel-2, rasterio, jpeg-2000

I'm trying to change dtype of a .jp2 Sentinel 2 image, with this code:

```
    with rasterio.open(tmp_file) as src:
    meta = src.meta
    meta.update(dtype=rasterio.uint16)
    array = src.read()
with rasterio.open(filename, 'w', **meta) as dst:
    dst.write_band(array.astype(rasterio.uint16), 1)
```

But once is stored, if I check the values of the array they have changed.

```
Original array: 

[[[10 10 10 ...  6  6  6]
  [10 10 10 ...  6  6  6]
  [10 10 10 ...  6  6  6]
  ...
  [10 10 10 ...  0  0  0]
  [10 10 10 ...  0  0  0]
  [ 4 10 10 ...  0  0  0]]]

Array when open new image: [[[21  8  8 ...  3 16 11]
  [ 8  0  0 ...  0  4  0]
  [ 8  0  0 ...  0  3  0]
  ...
  [ 7  0  0 ...  0  0  0]
  [20  7  7 ...  0  9  4]
  [ 9  3  1 ...  0  4  0]]]
```

And as you can see the transformation is not even consistent.

If I do the same but storing the image as a GTiff, then the values are preserved.

Do you why? Is there any way to avoid this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem that you're encountering can be traced back to lossy compression.

have a look at `https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/jp2openjpeg.html#lossless-compression`. Lossless compression can be achieved if all the following creation options are defined.

```
QUALITY=100
REVERSIBLE=YES
YCBCR420=NO (which is the default)
```

The following script should work and create reproducible result:

```
# Read
with rasterio.open(f_in) as src:
    img = src.read(1)
    profile = src.profile

# Update
profile.update(dtype='uint16', driver='JP2OpenJPEG')
img = img.astype('uint16')

# Write
with rasterio.open(f_out, 'w', QUALITY='100', REVERSIBLE='YES',YCBCR420='NO', **profile) as dst:
    dst.write(img, 1)
```